# Simple error for searching a rest service

Tags: spring, angular, rest, https

I  have a problem on my project, It was built in angular and spring boot . The Angular part , send requests to the back end. So I have two Enviroments at now, the first is the development and the Second is the staging. So the overral project works on developments, and in the staging the project didn't work. The message error is (in chrome web Browser ) :

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staging.server.com.br/srsan/cadastros/locais' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://staging.server.com.br:7434/public/api/v1/localidades/all'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The back end works fine, I tested in the postman.

So the code that didn't work in the enviroment.hom.ts was ( front-end)  :

```
import { dynamicValues } from './dynamic-values';

export const environment = {
  dynamicValues,
  env: 'staging',
  production: false,
  baseHref: '/srsan/',
  debug: false,
  api: { appBackend: 'http://staging.server.com.br:7434/public/api/' }
};
```

The code in the develops was (works fine):

```
import { dynamicValues } from './dynamic-values';

export const environment = {
  dynamicValues,
  production: false,
  baseHref: '/srsan/',
  debug: false,
  api: { appBackend: 'http://develops.server.com.br:7434/public/api/' }
};
```

I switched to https in the staging , but the error persists.

The sample code to called the back-end:

```
    private API_URL: string =environment.api.appBackend+'v1/item-pauta'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadAllItens(): Observable<ItemPautaResource[]> {
    return this.http.get<ItemPautaResource[]>(this.API_URL + "/all")
      .pipe(catchError(this.processarErros));
  }
```

The package.json has this parts:

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"clean": "node ./node_modules/.bin/shx rm -rf dist",
"generate-version-file": "node ./build-tasks/build-pre $1",
"start": "npm run generate-version-file -- --env=dev && ng serve",
"build": "npm run generate-version-file -- --env=dev && ng build",
"build:dev": "npm run generate-version-file -- --env=dev && ng build --configuration=development --base-href=/srsan/",
"build:hom": "npm run generate-version-file -- --env=stage && ng build --configuration=stage --base-href=/srsan/",
"build:prod": "npm run generate-version-file -- --env=prod && ng build --prod --base-href=/srsan/",
"build:stats": "npm run generate-version-file && ng build --prod --stats-json",
"build:pack": "cd dist && shx mv srsan-webapp srsan && bestzip srsan.zip srsan/*",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"bundle-report": "npm run build:stats && webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/srsan-webapp/stats.json"
```

},

so I use the command `npm build:dev` or `npm build:hom` to build the application;

Comment: Could you please check the configuration of your server? It seems that your staging (frontend) server is https secured. Then your backend calls should be https secured to.Currently you call your backend by "HTTP"

Comment: Thanks @JanRecker , I switched to http and didn't work, so I will verify in the configuration, I was asked this question in the suporting.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problems by redirect all the request to https in the server configs.